# The import com.example.myfirstapp.R can not be resolved

Tags: android

I have been working my way through the Tab menu tutorial and have come across multiple errors. After doing some research on here I found the common solution was to change the Import android.R to import com.example.myfirstapp.R.

This is giving me the error that this file cannot be resolved. Can anyone tell me why I can't import this file? I have a hunch from researching on here that eclipse has not built the file, but I have no idea how to build it as I am new to coding as this is just a hunch and may be completely wrong.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
```

[Edit}

```
i have removed the "com.example.myfirstapp.R" and have CMD-SIFT-O to restore the imports but i still have the following errors.
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the environment you're working in? What OS, what version of Eclipse,etc. It sounds like you're working on Android so I added that tag, but please fix it if I'm wrong. Also a link to the tutorial you're working through.

Comment: ahh sorry new to this yes I'm using android, eclipse v22.0.5. the tutorial is the Adding Action Buttons from the android developers page link. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `com.example.myfirstapp.R`  unless it is in a library. If it is in `com.example.myfirstapp`, remove it.

Also, trying cleaning your project and rebuilding it.

Comment: thank you i removed the com.example.myfirstapp.R but i now get error.
R. cannot be a resolved variable in the code

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        
    }

Comment: As I said, try cleaning and rebuilding your project and that should fix it. If the error persists, Ill need some more details like your development environment and the libraries youre using.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any files, pictures, etc in your drawable or assets folder with capital letters, spaces, or dashes. Just use plane old lowercase. Also, try to clean your project. Go to project > clean. Then restart eclipse. Hope this helps. Also eclipse won't reconize any changes in XML files without saving first. Make sure to save after you add a button, ect.